# Cannot find a version of 'com.google.code.gson:gson' that satisfies the version constraints when using firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, gson, android-room

**It does not occurred when remove `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.3.0'` dependency in my gradle and It causes only when to test not to run app**.

here is the full error message

```
Cannot find a version of 'com.google.code.gson:gson' that satisfies the version constraints: 
   Dependency path 'myapp:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-testing:2.2.1' --> 'androidx.room:room-migration:2.2.1' --> 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
   Constraint path 'myapp:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.gson:gson:{strictly 2.7}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.7
   Dependency path 'myapp:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.3.0' --> 'io.grpc:grpc-android:1.21.0' --> 'io.grpc:grpc-core:1.21.0' --> 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
```

What should I do?

Comment: Nope @PeterHaddad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can always check your dependencies tree like this: `gradlew app:dependencies` (that's assuming your module in question is called app; for linux you will likely have to call it like this `./gradlew app:dependencies`)

That said, your log seems to contain all you need already: room is using 2.8.0 and firebase is using 2.7. Please try to exclude gson transitive dependency, say, from room (`exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson'`) and let's see if that helps.

Comment: you mean like this?  androidTestImplementation ("androidx.room:room-testing:$rootProject.roomVersion") {
        exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson'
    }

Comment: Unbelievable! It works! How did you know? I've not even know gradle can manage explictly manage sub dependency of dependency.

Comment: ok.. this is exactly what I was looking for. worked for me!